# wxPython Changing Taskbar Icon During Runtime Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, wxpython, notifyicon

I have main.py and appIndicator.py files. I start appIndicator.py(which use wxPython library) from main.py as subprocess. When I have notificaion, I have to change appIndicator icon. However, I couldn't find any way to do that so when I need to change appIndicator icon, I kill subprocess from main.py, change icon file and start appIndicator as subprocess again but in Windows, when I do that, appIndicator icon is duplicated. Till the I take mouse pointer on old subprocess' icon, it stays there.

Is there any better way to change icon ?

What should I do to be able to clear old icon ?

Do you have any different suggestion ?

Thanks...

[image: duplicated icon SS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your change icon event handler, try calling the current icon's `RemoveIcon()` method and then its `Destroy()` method. That should remove it from the taskbar. Then you can create the new icon that should appear there. I believe you'll have to call the new icon's `SetIcon()` method to make it appear in the system tray.